# Anything free in Slack App Directory to auto reply when a user has certain statuses?

Tags: productivity, plug-in, slack

Is there anything free in [Slack app directory](https://slack.com/apps) that makes you auto reply (preferably by opening a thread) whenever your status is X or Y (like sick, away, vacation, etc.)?